# Kendo Grid - Manual delete function is ignored

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add some validation to a delete button my grid, so I am having the delete button execute a function when clicked, but it seems to be ignoring the function.  Here is the function:

```
function locDelete(e) {
    var len = this.dataSource.data().length;
    var item = $("#trespassed-location-list").data("kendoGrid").dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));

    if (len === 1) {
        alert("There must be at least one location.");
    }
    else {
        alert("This is in the else");
        //this.remove(item);
        //this.removeRow($(e.target).closest("tr"));
    }
}
```

I put the second alert in there for testing, neither alert is ever hit.  Here is the grid code, and the datasource:

```
 var PersId = $("#PersonId").val();
 var ds_locationsList = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: '@Url.Action("JsonPopulateTrespassList", "TrespassOrder")/' + PersId,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: "POST"
                    },
                destroy: {
                        url: '@Url.Action("JsonDeleteLocation", "TrespassOrder")',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: "POST"
                    }
        },
         parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
             if (operation == "destroy" && options.models) {
                 var values = {};
                 values["TrespassLocId"] = options.models[0].TrespassLocId;
                 return values;
             }
         },
         schema: {
            model: {
                id: "TrespassedLocId",
                fields: {
                    TrespassLocId: { editable: false},
                    LocationName: { editable: false }
                }
            }
        },
         pageSize: 20
 });


    $(document).ready(function () {

       $("#trespassed-location-list").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: ds_locationsList,
            sortable: true,
            height: "150px",
            width: "300px",
            editable: "inline",
            columns: [{
                field: "LocationName", title: "Trespassed Location(s)"
            }, {
                command: [{ name: "destroy", text: "Delete", click: locDelete }],
                width: "110px",
            }] 
       });
```

If I comment out the LocDelete function, I get a 'locDelete undefined' error, so I know the grid is looking for it.  Could the delete confirmation notice be messing things up?  But with the locDelete function as written above (with the remove code commented out, the row still gets removed from the database base and client side.  I have tried tracking it with firebug, but my breakpoints never get hit for the locDelete function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that while initializing the grid JavaScript uses `locDelete` and if not defined it complains (JavaScript itself) but then, by the end of Kendo UI Grid initialization, it defines a handler for some specific classes those corresponding to the default commands. If instead of defining the name as `destroy` you set it to `my_destroy`, it will work.

Comment: That worked, thanks.  So in the columns specifications, where it says command: [{ name: "validate_destroy", text: "Delete", click: locDelete }], that name is looking for a class?  So I assume kendo has a built in 'destroy' class, but because I changed it to validate_destroy, it finds no class and uses the 'click' property?